# CredentialsProvider for the bing map in windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bing-maps, windows-phone-8-emulator

I was developing a windows phone application in WP7.1, while adding map control we have to set a parameter name "CredentialsProvider". Now i have moved to WP8.0, here while adding map control i am not getting "CredentialsProvider" parameter.
and when i run my application on emulator, it's showing blue square in place of map control, is this because of not setting "CredentialsProvider" ?.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't need to use CredentialsProvider property in wp8 app, as  CredentialsProvider property is basically the bing api key which a developer issues from Microsoft to enjoy the extended services of bing maps Like making a route, Reverse GeoCoding, GeoCoding. All these services are available as a pert of the sdk in wp8 hence no need to set the attribute, that attribute was only meant till wp7.

Please let me know the problem and requirement in detail if still you havent got the solution.

Comment: while running my app on emulator, it is not showing contents of the map.

Comment: Output screen : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By0Y-Dca1cKjVG1QQUY3MVBQcFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what are you aiming at, I mean what do you want your app to perform?

Comment: i have added a map control on the page and it should display the content of the map that's it. but it is showing only blue box.

Comment: bing map do require Data connection too, do you have internet access in your emulator?