# Adding Bing Maps key credential to map. Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I'm trying to add my Bing maps key I got from here http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ but when I add the `credentials` property to the map like below it gives me the following errors. Is it a different method for adding to phone or have I made a mistake somewhere?

```
<maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" Credentials="my key..." ZoomLevel="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="603" LandmarksEnabled="True" PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" >

Error   1   The member "Credentials" is not recognized or is not accessible.
Error   2   The property 'Credentials' was not found in type 'Map'
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If using WP7:**

You need to add the CredentialsProvider attribute to the XAML:

`<my2:Map HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,23,0,0" 
   Name="map2" VerticalAlignment="Top"

   Loaded="map2_Loaded" 
   Height="534" 
   Width="436"
   CredentialsProvider=
"Ahk5en93JIJlP4ObG_CqLoLgWU22jhPFJbe52bOTjw_hYxB3EtthoVL"
 />`

The key above is taken from the maps portal website. See this guide for more info:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-use-the-bing-map-control-in-windows-phone-7/

**If using WP8:**

See here, this property is no longer used as the functionality that you use the API key for is built into the SDK, so no need to make any calls to MS servers.

[CredentialsProvider for the bing map in windows phone 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589870/credentialsprovider-for-the-bing-map-in-windows-phone-8-application)

Comment: okay, so I don't need to add credentials to map in a Windows phone 8 app, correct? When I upload the application the api call is in built?

Comment: The SDK includes functionality built in that you needed to call out to microsoft to before. Since there is no calls to MS's web services, there is no need for a key.